# Is the $C^{\infty}$ topology dependent on coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology

Given a manifold $M$, one can define the $C^{\infty}$ topology on $C^{\infty}(M)$ by the seminorms associated to compact sets $K$, $P_{K}^{s}(f) = \sup_{x \in K} \max_{|\alpha| \leq s} |D^{\alpha}f|$. However, this definition of seminorms is going to be dependent on the choice of the coordinates. Presumably, the resulting topology will not be dependent on the choice of the coordinates, but I wonder how to prove it.

The topology is induced by the metric $d(x,y) = \sum_{n(K,s)} 2^{-n(K,s)} \frac{p_{K}^{s}(x,y)}{1 + p_{K}^{s}(x,y)}$. Different seminorms are equivalent because they differ by a smooth transition function on a compact set, but this metric is some sort of sum of all the seminorms. How to control the equivalence of all the seminorms uniformly?

Comment: First show that a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges in the metric to $f$ of and only if $p_k^\alpha (f_n -f)\to 0$ for all $k,\alpha$. It should not be too hard to show that this latter property does not depend on the coordinates.

Comment: What is $n(K,s)$?